# mpirun the program with no output

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I am doing an mpi assignment.

My program is to let the user to input a list of data and we calculate the time that the program needs to search the data in the database(.csv).

The sequential program I have done wrote and it works fine. It can allow the user to input and then search the user input in the csv file and return the time needed.

But when I apply the mpi into the program, it can compile using mpicc . And when I run the program by using mpirun, it shows nothing. Can anyone help me to see what has happen ?
this is the example data inside the .csv file

===================================================

managerID,yearID,teamID,lgID,inseason,G,W,L,rank,plyrMgr

wrighha01m,1871,BS1,NA,1,31,20,10,3,Y

woodji01m,1871,CH1,NA,1,28,19,9,2,Y

paborch01m,1871,CL1,NA,1,29,10,19,8,Y

=======================================

my code

=============================================

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     //for string operations : strcpy & strtok
#include <time.h> 

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{ 

int n, myid, numprocs; 
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid); 

struct
{
    char managerID[50];
    char yearID[50];
    char teamID[10];
    char lgID[3];
    char inseason[7];
    char G[50];
    char W[50];
    char L[10];
    char rank[3];
    char plyrMgr[7];
}Managers[5000];

time_t start, end;      //variable used for compute time.

//double diff;
int choice;

int dataSize=0;
FILE *fp;
char buf[99999];        //max total array size
int i = 0, j;
fp=fopen("Managers.csv","r");

//ignore the commna delimiters, copy the value into each field's arrays.
 while( fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(Managers[i].managerID, strtok(buf,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].yearID, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].teamID, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].lgID, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].inseason, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].G, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].W, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].L, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].rank, strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Managers[i].plyrMgr, strtok(NULL,","));
    ++i;        //increment array
    dataSize++;     //counter for data size
}

char *s;
char str[5];
if(myid ==0){
    printf("\n\n Please input the data to be retrieved\n");
    printf(" Note : No space is allowed...\n");
    printf(" Sample Query : abc,123,def,321\n");
    printf(" Input =>");
    scanf ("%s", str);
}
MPI_Bcast(str, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // broadcast the information out

 start = clock(); // start the time


s = strtok (str, ",");
printf("\n");

//print header field
printf(" ManagerID");
printf("       YearID");
printf("      TeamID");
printf("      LgID");
printf("      InSeason");
printf("    Game");
printf("        Win");
printf("       Lose");
printf("        Rank");
printf("     PlyrMgr\n\n");

//print all the data
 while (s != NULL)
{
    int k;

    for (k =1; k<=dataSize; k++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s,Managers[k].managerID) == 0)
        {
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].managerID);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].yearID);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].teamID);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].lgID);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].inseason);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].G);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].W);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].L);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].rank);
            printf(" %10s",Managers[k].plyrMgr);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    s = strtok (NULL, ",");
}

end = clock(); // end time
double diff = (((double)end - (double)start)/1000000.0F) * 1000;

if(myid==0){

    printf(" Time Taken : %.5f seconds \n", diff);
}


MPI_Finalize(); 

}
```

Comment: How are you running? Are you running this application on a cluster? single pc?